# Adding LAPACK libraries in Fortran Make file

Tags: makefile, fortran, fortran90, gfortran, lapack

I am writing a code in Fortran90. I require to use dgesv function from LAPACK libraries. I have several subroutines that I am compiling with gfortran using a `make file`. I can link the Lapack libraries with gfortran by using

```
gfortran test.f -L/path/to/libs -llapack -lblas
```

Can anyone help in how to add these libraries to my make file? My make file is below:

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .f .o .f90
#
LIBDIR = lib
UNAME := $(shell uname)

DEFINE = 
FCOMP  = gfortran
FOPTS  = -fdefault-real-8 -g -fbounds-check -fbacktrace -O2 -Wline-truncation
F90OPTS = -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none
#FOPTS = -fPIC -g

OBJS =  read_model_2d_elasto.o output_2d_elasto.o 2d_elastostatics_FEM.o stiffness_2d_elasto.o stress_strain_2d_elasto.o \

XLIBS  = -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lX11 -lpthread 
GLIBS  = -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lGLU -lGL -lX11 -lXext -lpthread

#default:   2d_elastostatics_FEM techop
all: 2d_elastostatics_FEM 

ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
  2d_elastostatics_FEM:$(OBJS)
    $(FCOMP)  -g $(OBJS) -o 2d_elastostatics_FEM 
else
  2d_elastostatics_FEM:$(OBJS)
    $(FCOMP)  -g -static $(OBJS) -o 2d_elastostatics_FEM
endif

.f.o:; $(FCOMP) -c -o $@ $(FOPTS) $*.f
.f90.o:; $(FCOMP) -c -o $@ $(FOPTS) $(F90OPTS) $*.f90

clean:

    -rm -f 2d_elastostatics_FEM $(OBJS) *.mod *.x *.exe
```

Comment: Use the sme way you use for XLIBS and GLIBS.

Comment: @VladimirF I dont understand. What directory would I put my libraries? Can you please explain. I have lapack libraries in a separate directory that I made using Cmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sme way you use for XLIBS and GLIBS in your Makefile

```
BLIBS = -L/path/to/libs -llapack -lblas
```

...

```
ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
  2d_elastostatics_FEM:$(OBJS)
    $(FCOMP)  -g $(OBJS) -o 2d_elastostatics_FEM $(BLIBS)
else
  2d_elastostatics_FEM:$(OBJS)
    $(FCOMP)  -g -static $(OBJS) -o 2d_elastostatics_FEM $(BLIBS)
endif
```